# generated signed apk from android studio gives error "there was a problem parsing the package" on installing on device

Tags: java, android, apk

During testing on emulator or device through physical device the app works fine.
but when i try to generate a signed apk in the android studio , the Signed App generated donot install on real device. it shows the error there was "error in parsing the package".
i tried
**Minify enabled false/true**
**i tried deleting .gradle and .idea**
*tried multiple keys**`enter code here`
Nothing worked. plz hlp.

My Gradle

```
{
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reg.nsb"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the debug build is installed already on device if yes then remove the debug build which already installed in your device and install signed apk again

Hope it may help you

Comment: Sir i have no debug build installed on my device. Also the signed apk generated by android studio has very less size  between 1-2 MB

Comment: Please try with lintoptions{. Checkreleasebuilds false abortonerror false}  dexoptions,. Compileoptions etc.. in gradle android{}

Comment: no luck. I reinstalled the android studio and create a new project with hello word  and that project also gives the same error when i generate the signed apk

Comment: Please verify this point (1)Please check allow installation from other sources in phone settings
(2)check the downloaded .apk is fully not downloaded or corrupted
(3) check the app is compatible with the Hardware or version of the OS you are using or not. ....it may help you

Answer (score 0):

-Hi, I was facing similar error, the problem seems to be the targetsdkversion.
My targetsdkversion was 31, and it was giving parsing error on android 12 devices, but it did install on my android 9 device.

- when installing from external source
- I changed it to 29, and it seems to be installing now on my android 12 device

I hope it helps you